# Is depth significant in CSS nested properties

Tags: html, css, syntax, nested

The title of the question gives the wrong idea, I think, but I couldn't think of a proper way to word this...

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
    <form id="searchbox">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="searchterm">Searchterm: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="searchterm" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to style the table cells using CSS. Is it valid to do this:

```
div#form-wrapper td {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
div#form-wrapper form table tr td {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

I would think the latter is syntactically correct, since that's how the HTML elements are nested. I know I could easily test this in a JSFiddle (which I haven't, partially due to languor), but I want to know whether it's syntactically/semantically okay as well, not just if it works or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Well if do you first one it forms all the td's inside form-wrapper. The latter is more specific

Comment: Otherwise, it's entirely acceptable?

Comment: It works but maybe not the way you want it. If you want to target a specific td you should nest it all the way through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is more accurate and will have a higher importance due to its increased targets. They will both do the same as it stands in your example however if you was to do

```
div#form-wrapper form table tr td {
    font-size: 16pt;
}
div#form-wrapper td {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

the second one wouldnt overwrite the first due to its higher importance. Also the first one requires the td to be inside a form tag whereas the second one will style a td that follows the conditions and is or isnt inside a form tag.

Read [This](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/css-specificity-scoring/) on CSS specificity which explains how more targets = more specificity and therefore higher importance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, css has specificity rules. If two rules have opposing rules for a particular element, then the one with the "more specific" selectors wins.

e.g.

```
#foo {
   color: red
}

div#foo {
   color: blue;
}


<div id="foo">Hi there</div>
```

This div would come out blue, because `div#foo` is more specific than just a plain `#foo`.